# JSON -> Immutable custom Java object. Insufficient data in JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I use `Jackson` to deserialize JSON to an immutable custom Java object. Here is the class:

```
final class DataPoint {
  private final int count;
  private final double mean;

  @JsonCreator
  DataPoint(
      @JsonProperty("count") int count,
      @JsonProperty("mean") double mean) {
    if (count <= 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
    }
    this.count = count;
    this.mean = mean;
  }

  // getters...
}
```

Here is the JSON I deserialize:

```
{
  "count": 1,
  "mean": 2
}
```

It works fine. Now I break the JSON, i.e. remove one proprerty:

```
{
  "count": 1
}
```

The deserialization code is:

```
String json = "..."; // the second JSON
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
DataPoint data  = mapper.readValue(json, DataPoint.class);
```

Now I get `count == 1`, and `mean == 0.0`. Instead, I would like the Jackson to throw an exception, sine one of the required field is missing in the JSON. How can I archive that?

Thank you a lot, guys!

Comment: What if you change to `@JsonProperty("mean") Double mean` and check whether it is null or not?

Comment: @StanislavL: Well, it's a kind of a solution. Than you a lot! Am I right there is no means in Jackson letting me to get what I want witout boxing?

Comment: @StanislavL You won't be able to tell if it's missing, or present but set to null.

Comment: @shmosel it fails on null anyway. It's not possible to convert null to double but your answer is better +1. I suggested just a workaround.

Comment: @StanislavL It's possible that the implicit conversion from null to 0 is acceptable, as long as the property is defined. Your solution would throw an exception in either case. Of course, only OP can say if that's a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using a constructor, you can enable [`DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES) to throw an exception on missing properties:

```
String json = "..."; // the second JSON
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES);
DataPoint data  = mapper.readValue(json, DataPoint.class);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! You suggestion just works fine. I jsut needed to increate the version of the Jersey BOM. Thankx again, dude!